# Bash - Archive multiple subfolders from mounted fs to local folder

Tags: bash, for-loop, rar

I thought my idea was easy but since i've spend 4h now, I thought I could need help.

I want to create rar-archives from a music library that is stored on a mounted fs, with each archive having the subfolders name out of the library but I want the archives being directly created on the local system.

Both of the following solutions leaded to created archives in the library but not on my local fs.

```
 for folder in /mnt/storage01/lib/audiobook/entertainment*/; do rar a -m5 -v100m -r "${folder%/}.rar" "$folder"; done
```

or

```
find /mnt/storage01/lib/audiobook/entertainment/. -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -exec rar a -m5 -v100m -r -w {}.rar {} \;
```

adding

```
 ... -v100m -r -w "../home/{}.rar" {} \;
```

at the end unfortunately leaded just to one archive named "home.rar" where all subfolders got collected. At least in my local fs..

What am I overseeing?

Comment: Have a look at my answer and vote if you like it if you don't mind ...

Comment: To less reputation to vote, sry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use find with read/while :

```
    # -- sample code (replace echo output with actual command) --
    save_folder="/tmp/"
    find /tmp/testing/ -maxdepth 1  -type d | while read fpath; do
        echo "rar a -m5 -v100m -r \"${save_folder}$(basename ${fpath%.*}).rar\" \"$fpath\""     
    done
```

output (just echoing) :

```
rar a -m5 -v100m -r "/tmp/14.rar" "/tmp/testing/14"
rar a -m5 -v100m -r "/tmp/80.rar" "/tmp/testing/80"
rar a -m5 -v100m -r "/tmp/13.rar" "/tmp/testing/13"
rar a -m5 -v100m -r "/tmp/16.rar" "/tmp/testing/16"
rar a -m5 -v100m -r "/tmp/2.rar" "/tmp/testing/2"
rar a -m5 -v100m -r "/tmp/100.rar" "/tmp/testing/100"
rar a -m5 -v100m -r "/tmp/17.rar" "/tmp/testing/17"
```